Cannot register new ACME account on vault ACME endpoint
I have setup a new instance of Hashicorp's Vault, I followed the tutorial instructions on Hashicorp's own website on how to configure ACME. However, I am unable to register new ACME accounts using UACME. The process simply quits after a 400 response from Vault with:
uacme: acme_post: return code 400, json=
{
    "type": "urn:ietf:params:acme:error:accountDoesNotExist",
    "detail": "An account with this key does not exist: The request specified an account that does not exist",
    "subproblems": null
}


Was an issue with uacme, it did not reply with a new-nonce. It is remedied in main branch.
